# What is the difference between Unity vs c++?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, xamarin, multiplatform

What could be the difference between using SDK like UNITY/xamarin and (native development programming language + c++) for multi platform? It seems UNITY/xamarin, is pretty cheap compared to having to learn new languages. It seems though, big companies use the native language and c++. **What are the FACTUAL benefits and setbacks in terms of SPEED?**

Answer (score 0):

In my general programming experience, compiled C/C++ programs generally run faster than most other compiled languages, like Java or even compiled python, and almost always run faster than interpreted languages like uncompiled Python or JavaScript. If speed is an absolute first priority, i would stick with C++. Also, C++ is the most portable language i've ever seen. it runs on hundreds of different architectures, from the low-end RISC processors and machines like the Arduino and Raspberry Pi, as well as some of the more common and more widely used instruction sets like x86 and x86-64. Because of this, I recommend C++.